# How to determine the maximum scale according to Image resolution

Tags: ios, image, resources, dpi

Actually I want to scale Image used in iPhone to iPad.

I have one Image of resolution 300 dpi.

Its size is 320 * 127.

**Maximum how much can I scale this Image so that It will not blur ?**

As I am stuck with the relation between resolution of an Image and its maximum dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understand the idea of resolution.

Your requirements are simply "so that It will not blur." If you scale an image larger *or* smaller than its native resolution (which I'm assuming is your "320 * 127"), the display device has to either reduce or increase the number of pixels. It does this by interpolating, or "blurring" the pixel colors.

Now, if you're asking how much can you alter an image's scale so that a human eye can't tell the difference, that's a different question.

Comment: Yes you are right but some ho I need to increase the resolution of an image is is not possible.As I think now.

Comment: There are a few tools out there to *reduce* the amount of blur that is introduced when you scale an image, but those are more like Photoshop plugins than programming tools. (http://www.alienskin.com/blowup/index.aspx was one that I found from a quick search)